# Bamini font tex convert to english font using c#.net

Tags: c#

i have record save for bamini font text based in db. but i have received tat data was convert to english font text using c#.net application

advance tahanks

Answer (score 0):

Your database will only store the character data, not the specific font it was written in.

If you've written Tamil characters then as long as you set your database field to store Unicode or UTF-8 data, e.g. used the nvarchar data type if you're using SQL Server, then you character data will have saved correctly. If you aren't, then it might not depending on your database's default code page. However either way it is up to the application that reads back the data to pick a font that can render the characters correctly.

I don't know if you've written a UI or a web application. If it's a web application then again as long as you serve the page as UTF-8 then the characters should survive correctly and as long as the reader has a default font that supports the Tamil characters then it should render correctly - or you could add a Bamini font style to the text to try and help. If it's a UI application then you'll need to set your application's default font or the specific font for the text labels or fields to Bamini.